# Elasticsearch sink only get new messages and not the previous one using kafka-connect-elasticsearch + timestamp SMT

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the kafka-connect-elasticsearch plugin to get message from my kafka to Elasticsearch.
My data in kafka contain a date field (timestamp format).

My first issue was that when I use this plugin, Elasticsearch index didn't recognize the date field as a date type but as a long ...
I kind of solve this using an SMT transformation in my connector configuration.

Here is my current configuration that allow me to push data in Elastic :

```
{
  "name": "elasticsearch-sink-test",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test.test",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "type.name": "kafka-connect",
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink-test",
    "Batch.size": 100,
    "max.buffered.records": 1000,
    "Max.retries": 10,
    "Retry.backoff.ms": 1000,
    "flush.timeout.ms": 20000,
    "max.in.flight.requests": 3
    "transforms": "date",
    "transforms.date.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.date.target.type": "Date",
    "transforms.date.field": "date",
    "transforms.date.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  }
}
```

My issue right now is that : 
Elasticsearch doesn't get all the previous messages stored in kafka but only the new one (all the new message that get push to kafka after I started the Elasticsearch connector).

How can I configure the connector to make elastic get all the messages ?
Is there any workaround the make elastic "understand" that the date field is a timestamp ?

(For information, my data origin are a MongoDB with the debezium CDC connector)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I configure the connector to make elastic get all the messages?

Just like a regular Kafka consumer, you need to set the offsets to the earliest

```
consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

> Is there any workaround the make elastic "understand" that the date field is a timestamp ?

Yes, using index or dynamic mappings in Elasticsearch. By default, all ingested numbers are only numeric values. Only properly formatted date strings actually become indexed as dates. If you don't control the Elasticsearch server, or the index settings, this is usually something setup by the admin of that system

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work.
I add "consumer.auto.offset.reset": "earliset" at the end of my config file and nothing change.
Is it the good way to setup the offset ? If no how to do that please

Comment: Since you've already started the connector once, then it's set to be the latest offset... You need to reset the consumer group or rename the connector. I've verified this setting works, but you spelled earliest incorrectly in your comment

Comment: Works perfectly now.
I renamed the connector and correct the typo ...
Thanks